# Which file extension should be in for MediaWiki installation for pecl issue

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I am trying to install Mediawik in my ubuntu apache2 server.
As the Mediawiki installation page shows up

```
Warning: The intl PECL extension is not available to handle Unicode normalization, falling back to slow pure-PHP implementation.
```

I had followed some searched article as follow :

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
You will be prompted to confirm the install. Just press “y” and enter. If all goes well you should see it download and install the php-pear package.

Now you will need to install the php5-dev package to get the necessary PHP5 source files to compile additional modules. Enter the following from a shell prompt:

sudo apt-get install php5-dev
If you do not install the php5-dev package and try to install a PECL extension using “pear install”, you will get the following error:

sh: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize’ failed
The PECL_HTTP extension requires an additional dependency package to be installed. You can probably skip this for other extensions:

sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
Now we are finally ready to actually install the extension. From a shell prompt enter following but substitute “pecl_http” with the PECL extension name you are installing:

sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

now I can't figure out what file extension name should go in the "pecl_http" side.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`.